# Rails - simple_form, include a named blank object in a collection on new and edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple_form  which I am trying to get to always include a blank item in it, as a 'nil' value in that field has a special meaning in this database.
In order to make it more obvious for end users, I also want to title it with something along the lines of "(select if none)".

I'm currently doing this, but it only inserts the 'blank' item when creating a new object, not when editing one.

```
# _child_form.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for @child do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.association :parent, :collection => @parents, :prompt => "(select if none)" %>

  <%= f.button.submit %>
<% end %>
```

.

```
# child_controller.rb

def new
  @child = Child.new
  @parents = Parent.all
end

def edit
  @child = Child.find(params[:id])
  @parents = Parent.all
end
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You want to use `:include_blank`, not `:prompt`

```
<%= f.association :parent, :collection => @parents, :include_blank => "(select if none)" %>
```

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. I've read that documentation enough times and obviously kept skipping over that bit.

Comment: Note to self:
    ```include_blank: :All```
will NOT work.  
    ```include_blank: 'All'```
does...

Comment: I also had to chose the selected value or else the blank option would not display first and selected within the dropdown, like this: `selected: ""`